# ios 7 simulator facebook integration dialogbox's setting button is not working

Tags: ios, facebook, ios7, settings

I am working on IOS 7. I want to integrate Facebook in my App. Here is my code to share the post,

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        SLComposeViewController *faceBook = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];      
        [faceBook setInitialText:@"This is my first post by IOS App"];
        // show in the view controller.
        [self presentViewController:faceBook animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It did not show any thing i.e. The control does not enter the if statement.

If I comment the if statment. It shows dialog box to setup facebook account with 2 buttons "Setting" and "cancel".

The problem is that, if i click on "Settings" button, Nothing is happen. Only the view will disappear.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. What I do.

goto IOS Simulator -> settings -> facebook.

Just I login in my facebook account and run the application. It is working Fine.

May be it is helpfull for some one.